# How to prevent Google from changing your /etc/hosts file when you restart the network service?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Whenever I change the /etc/hosts file and restart the network service, Google overwrites the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is impossible to do. Your server does not directly contain a public IP address. Yes, this screws things up with certain pieces of software, such as ISPConfig. There literally is no way to run ISPConfig on Google currently. Thankfully several other web hosting control panels (cPanel and InerWorx) work with a little bit of hacky configuration. If you want to know how to configure them, reply below.